# How to load datepicker individually in textboxes?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, calendar

I am using pretty event calendar and I want to show date-picker calendar on every individual text focus.

Datepicker uses selector string to trigger the calendar.So lets say these are the two elements in HTML like this.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Select Date">
<div class="dd"></div>
```

and this is how datepicker jquery library works

```
$('.dd').calendar({
      trigger: '.datepicker',
})
```

So calendar will trigger on dd when datepicker input is focused in.Now I want to handle this for multiple elements individually for datepicker class.Problem is that it triggers on all elements with datepicker class.

How to do that?

Comment: Have you considered using an `id` for each input ?

Comment: Ya but '.datepicker' is only selector not the object.So How to get individual selector?

Comment: You can do: `$('#IDofElement').calendar`

Comment: then I have to write the method for each ID

Comment: Yes. That is the proper way for my opinion. I also added this as an answer.